# Cms page custom layout update file for multiple pages - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: layout, magento2.3.4, cms-pages

In Magento 2.3.4 you can add custom layout update via XML files, using

```
cms_page_view_selectable_<PAGEIDENTIFIER>_<CUSTOMNAME>.xml
```

format.

But what if I want to apply this layout update on 20 CMS pages? Do I have to create a separate XML file for each page? Is there any way I can apply a layout update XML file on multiple CMS pages?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to apply an a layout update to multiple layout handles with just one XML file.

What you could do, is add a custom layout handle to all CMS pages where you want the layout to be updated. Then you can create one layout XML for that handle which is applied to all pages with that custom handle.

To do that you need to write a plugin for the `prepareResultPage` method of `\Magento\Cms\Helper\Page`. This can be done is your module by adding/modifing the folling files:

`<module-dir>/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Helper\Page">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="vendorModulePage" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper\PagePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`<module-dir>/Plugin/Helper/PagePlugin.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper;

class PagePlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * PagePlugin constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
    ) {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page|bool $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page|bool
     */
    public function afterPrepareResultPage(\Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page) {
            if ($this->isHandleApplicable()) {
                $result->addHandle('cms_custom_handle');
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isHandleApplicable()
    {
        if (in_array($this->page->getIdentifier(), ['identifier1', 'identifier2', 'home'])) {
            $isApplicable = true;
        } else {
            $isApplicable = false;
        }

        return $isApplicable;
    }
}
```

You can edit the `isHandleApplicable` method to match your needs. In my example the layout handle `cms_custom_handle` is added when the identifier of the current page is `identifier1`, `identifier2` or `home`

You can now create a `cms_custom_handle.xml` that is applied to all pages that match your conditions in the `isHandleApplicable` method.

Comment: It's working? I have checked above code but, not working in my case.

Comment: @PayalPatel I'm using this exact code in a production system, so it's definitely working. Did you refresh cache and emptied your generation folder? Did you correctly update the namespace to match your module? Do you have any third party extensions that modify cms functionality?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the namespace to match with module. It's correct. I have not any third party extensions. I am working on local server with installed Magento version 2.3.4

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I can help you without having a look at your code and folder structure. Just to be safe try the following (I assume you work on Linux or MacOS): open a terminal at your magento root folder and execute `rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/* && bin/magento cache:clear` and try again. If it doesn't work I would suggest to open a question and post your code and folder structure. I will have a look at your profile on monday and try to answer it.

Comment: Okay, I will try as soon as possible. If can not success then I will post code.